# Why scripts run as user but not as a cron?

Tags: bash, centos, cron

I have a script that checks to see if port 4000 is open and listening, if it is return true, else start a service that also outputs a logfile. The script runs fine if I execute it as a user, but if I add it as a cron it doesn't run. I'm logged in as root, the script is owned by root, the script has executable permissions, and I am running `crontab -e` as root.

```
#!/bin/bash
if lsof -Pi :4000 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
    return 1
else
    seoserver -p 4000 start > /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/seoserver.log &
fi
```

And here is my cron

```
*/5     *       *       *       *       /usr/bin/seoStart
```

Comment: you should monitor you cron jobs to see what is actually going on, /var/log/cron might help, also you can redirect output to some file and check as well what is the issue from cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron doesn't start with common environment variables that your user has, including $PATH.

You have the full path in your cron, which is good, but you need to add it to your script as well.

```
which lsof
```

and

```
which seoserver
```

will give you the full path. Modify your script to use that instead of `lsof` and `seoserver`.

Comment: Is there any security concern with opening up the path inside of /etc/crontab to include the paths that my user has available, or should I really be doing this within my bash script?

Comment: Any security concerns would be pretty minor, but best practice would be to update the script.

Comment: I think that depends on where you're expanding your `$PATH` to.  If it's writable to users or highly nonstandard, use the full path.  If it's merely something like `/usr/local/bin`, that should be safe to add in the crontab and may save you from some future hair-pulling.